# How to get a function within ConstantArray to evaluate for each list element?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, evaluation, random

Here is my code example:

`ConstantArray[RandomInteger[{1, 5}], 10]`

However as my output I get something like

```
{3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}
```

A more complex example:

```
test := Module[{a, b, c}, (a = RandomInteger[{1, 100}]; 
b = RandomInteger[{1, 100}]; c = RandomInteger[{1, 100}]; 
If[TrueQ[a < b] == True && TrueQ[b < c] == True, True, False])]
```

Which chooses 3 random integers a, b, and c and returns True if b is between a and c, False otherwise.
However, plugging in

```
ConstantArray[test, 10]
```

just gives a list of 10 True's or 10 False's.

How can I construct a list for which a function like this is evaluated for every element in the list, rather than just evaluated once with that single output repeated? What function would work better than ConstantArray here?

Comment: For this particular example, `RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 10]` would do.

Comment: I was just giving a simpler example to what I am actually trying to do. I will edit in the more complex one to be more clear.

Comment: `ConstantArray` takes its first argument, _evaluates it_ and copies the result into an array whose size is prescribed by the second argument. That's why the entries are not "random".

Comment: Is there a different function that is similar but which would evaluate each time?

Comment: You could use `Table[test,10]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table) instead:

```
SeedRandom[1];
Tally @ Table[test, 100]
```

> {{False, 88}, {True, 12}}

On the other hand, it would be faster to create a random matrix and then post-process. For example:

```
SeedRandom[1];
Tally[
    Less @@@ RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {10^6, 3}]
] //AbsoluteTiming

SeedRandom[1];
Tally @ Table[test, 10^6] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.699966, {{False, 837811}, {True, 162189}}}
>
> {7.77069, {{False, 837811}, {True, 162189}}}

Answer (score 1):

```
a = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {10}];
b = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {10}];
c = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {10}];
uff = Thread[#1 < #2 < #3 &[a, b, c]];
Grid@Transpose[{a, b, c , uff}] // TeXForm
```

gives:

$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
 46 & 93 & 92 & \text{False} \\
 32 & 70 & 12 & \text{False} \\
 89 & 37 & 63 & \text{False} \\
 4 & 7 & 73 & \text{True} \\
 47 & 67 & 61 & \text{False} \\
 90 & 11 & 79 & \text{False} \\
 9 & 55 & 24 & \text{False} \\
 95 & 14 & 10 & \text{False} \\
 60 & 91 & 17 & \text{False} \\
 79 & 33 & 68 & \text{False} \\
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll[test]
test[n_] := Module[{
   a = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, n],
   b = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, n],
   c = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, n]
   },
  MapThread[((#1 < #2) && (#2 < #3)) &, {a, b, c}]
  ]
test[10]
```

Of course in this particular case you could just

```
test[n_] := Module[{
   ints = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {3, n}]
   },
  MapThread[((#1 < #2) && (#2 < #3)) &, ints]
  ]
```